# How to calculate staff-hours using Open Project?

Tags: pm-software, tools

Using Open Project, how can one calculate staff-hours?

Using `Project -> Project Information -> Statistics`, is `work` it? ("Work" is 1,219 hours in my example below)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Work is indeed effort-hours, rather than duration.
Someone works for two hours on a task over two days results in 2 work hours, and 2 Days of duration.